# Can I apply form schengen visa in 1 country and travel from another

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, malta

I am a Indian national staying in UK on a work permit. My question is, If I apply for Schengen visa in UK to visit Malta, is it mandatory that I have to travel from UK or can I travel from India using the same Schengen Visa?

Comment: Pretty sure this question is answered already on this site.Short answer: No problem if your are applying from your (current) place of residency.

Comment: @DCTLib I thought so too, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no requirement to enter the Schengen area by departing from any particular country. In fact most countries have no such requirements at all.